# Saving incremental int variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

I need to save a variable that increments every time a user hits a button within the app. I've been trying to do that with `NSUserDefaults` with no success. Here's the code I'm using:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:i++ forKey:@"AppCount"];
```

When I output this in the log, however, I keep getting `0`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This line of code seems fine. Maybe the error is in another part of your code.

Comment: have you synchronised userdefaults ?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried synchronizing the defaults. Even when logging the variable `i`, I keep getting `1` returned over and over. I'm declaring `i` as an instance variable in this class, should I be doing something different with it?

Comment: OK, I'm finally getting it to increment after setting `i` to a static variable, but it's not actually saving - when I reopen the app, the count is back to 0.

Comment: @bmueller See the edit I just made to my post below, it may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

After each time you change the value of your integer.

Quoting Apple's documentation on `synchronize`:

> Writes any modifications to the persistent domains to disk and updates
>   all unmodified persistent domains to what is on disk.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize

So with this modification, your final code should look like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:i++ forKey:@"AppCount"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**EDIT:** Actually on second thought, give this a try:

I think the problem is using i++ assumes that the application will always be able to keep track of the count, and every time you re-enter the application i gets reset.

The following works, I just tested it.

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"AppCount"]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:i forKey:@"AppCount"];
}else{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"AppCount"] + 1 forKey:@"AppCount"];
}
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Where and how are you declaring `i`? Using this code, I'm back to getting 0 every time I call the log. (This is how I'm calling the log, in case I'm doing that wrong: `int log = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"AppCount"]; NSLog(@"Pic count: %d", log);`

Comment: @bmueller I didn't actually even declare "i" leaving you open to do it your self incase you wanted a variable starting point. If that isn't the case you can just use "0".

Comment: OK, it's incrementing again, but still not saving... When I quit, relaunch the app, and hit the button, the log says my count is back to 0.

Comment: Are you including this line for line how I typed it? including synchronize?

Comment: Yep. It's in an IBAction button method, if that makes any difference... Not sure why it would.

Comment: That's strange, if you have my entire if statement as listed above this should be working. Try deleting the app of your device and cleaning targets in Xcode to completely dump NSUserDefaults. Reinstall the app on your device and if it still doesn't work, edit your post to show me the entire code in your IBAction.

Comment: And... that did it. Thanks so much for walking me through this, my friend!

Comment: @bmueller Any time! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Static NSUIInteger appCount=0; 
in the function user taps increase it value appCount++;
that keeps the value in function calls within the app. after app closing you write it to file.

Comment: I'm finally getting `appCount` to increment by using a `static NSInteger`, but it's not saving when I close the app.

Comment: you can add a variable to info.plist file then assign store value in it before closing the app and you can access info.plist date like

  NSString *finalPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
[plistData objectForKey:@"RemoteURL"];

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

   countFirst= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"Counter"];

    countFirst++;

}
```

**Write this wherever you want to increment.**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:countFirst++ forKey:@"Counter"];
```